# How to take the value of the checked row in list view, and get the prefered text field?

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I fulfill the **AlertDIalog** and **ListView** with two values `Name` and `id`, and I cannot find conclusion оr the right way, when i checked some CheckBoxes, i need the value of the Checked/Selected rows of (id's text) to save.

```
    @OnClick(R.id.group_delete)    
    void deleteGroup() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog4 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PreviewActivity.this);

    LayoutInflater inflater2 = getLayoutInflater();
    View convertView2 = (View) inflater2.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_delete_group, null);
    dialog4.setView(convertView2);

    ListView listView2 = (ListView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.listViewGroup);

    final List<Item> groupList = this.getGroup();

    CustomAdapter listAdapter2 = new CustomAdapter(getBaseContext(), groupList);

    // listAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

    convertView2.setTag(dialog4);

 //   SparseBooleanArray sp = listView2.getCheckedItemPositions();

    listView2.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) -> {
        // Get user selected item.
        Object itemObject = adapterView.getAdapter();

        Item itemDto = (Item) itemObject;

        CheckBox itemCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.checkMark5);
        listAdapter2.setCheckedItem(position);
    });


    ImageView delete = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.del_group);
    delete.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {

        CheckBox itemCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.checkMark5);

        Iterator<String> it = listAdapter2.getCheckedItems().values().iterator();
        for (int i=0;i<listAdapter2.getCheckedItems().size();i++){
            //Do whatever
       //                String result = "";

       //                ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
       //                for (int y = 0; y < resultList.size(); y++) {
       //                        result += String.valueOf(resultList.get(i)) + "\n";
       //                    }
       //                if (result.matches("")) {
       ////
       //                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select some thing from list to show",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                    }

    //                else {
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                    }


                listAdapter2.getItem(Integer.parseInt(it.next()));
            }

        //   List<Item> resultList = listAdapter2.getCheckedItems();

    //                    for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
    //                        result += String.valueOf(resultList.get(i)) + "\n";
    //                    }

    //                    listAdapter2.getCheckedItemPositions().toString();
    //
    //                    if (result.matches("")) {
    //
    //                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select some thing from list to show",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                    }
    //                    else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                    }


        //   shared.setSharedPreferencesString(Constants.ID, size2);


        listAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });

    listView2.setAdapter(listAdapter2);
    listView2.setTag(dialog4);

    AlertDialog alert4 = dialog4.create();

    alert4.show();

    alert4.getWindow().

            setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.argb(0, 100, 100, 100)));
}

public List<Company> getCompanies() {
    return mCompanies;
}

private List<Item> getGroup() {


    ArrayList<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> groups2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Group group2 : mRepository.getCompanies().get(posit).getGroups()) {


        groups2.add(group2.getId());
    }

    for (Group group1 : mRepository.getCompanies().get(posit).getGroups()) {

        groups.add(group1.getName());


    }


    List<Item> ret = new ArrayList<Item>();

    int length = groups.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {


        String itemText2 = groups.get(i);
        String itemText3 = groups2.get(i);


        Item dto = new Item();
        dto.setChecked(false);
        dto.setIdText(itemText3);
        dto.setItemText(itemText2);



        ret.add(dto);

    }
    return ret;

}
```

**Item Class:**

```
public class Item { 

private boolean checked ;
private String itemText = "";
private String IdText = "";
private String IdText2 = "";

public String getIdText2() {
    return IdText2;
}

public void setIdText2(String idText2) {
    IdText2 = idText2;
}

public String getIdText() {
    return IdText;
}

public void setIdText(String idText) {
    IdText = idText;
}



public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public String getItemText() {
    return itemText;
}

public void setItemText(String itemText) {
    this.itemText = itemText;
}}
```

**CustomAdapter :**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Item> ItemList ;

public HashMap<String, String> checked = new HashMap<String, String>();

private Context ctx;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, List<Item> ItemList) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.ItemList = ItemList;
}

public void setCheckedItem(int item) {

    if (checked.containsKey(String.valueOf(item))) {
        checked.remove(String.valueOf(item));
    } else {
        checked.put(String.valueOf(item), String.valueOf(item));
    }
}

public HashMap<String, String> getCheckedItems() {
    return checked;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ItemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return ItemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ItemViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if (convertView != null) {
        viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {

        convertView = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.custom, null);

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkMark5);

        TextView listItemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_unit_id5);

        TextView tetx = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tekst5);

        TextView textId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_number5);

        viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(convertView);

        viewHolder.setItemCheckbox(checkbox);
        viewHolder.setItemTextView(listItemText);
        viewHolder.setIdTextView(textId);
        viewHolder.setIdTextView2(tetx);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    Item items = ItemList.get(position);
    viewHolder.getItemCheckbox().setChecked(items.isChecked());
    viewHolder.getItemTextView().setText(items.getItemText());
    viewHolder.getIdTextView().setText(items.getIdText());
    viewHolder.getIdTextView2().setText(items.getIdText2());

    return convertView;
}}
```

**ViewHolder :**

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private CheckBox itemCheckbox;
private TextView IdTextView;
private TextView itemTextView;
private TextView IdTextView2;

public TextView getIdTextView2() {
    return IdTextView2;
}

public void setIdTextView2(TextView idTextView2) {
    IdTextView2 = idTextView2;
}

public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
}

public TextView getIdTextView() {
    return IdTextView;
}

public void setIdTextView(TextView idTextView) {
    IdTextView = idTextView;
}

public CheckBox getItemCheckbox() {
    return itemCheckbox;
}

public void setItemCheckbox(CheckBox itemCheckbox) {
    this.itemCheckbox = itemCheckbox;
}

public TextView getItemTextView() {
    return itemTextView;
}

public void setItemTextView(TextView itemTextView) {
    this.itemTextView = itemTextView;
}  }
```

Comment: you already have boolean `isChecked`. you can use that. Make a function of returntype a list<Integer> and in that you check the list in your adapter that if value is checked then respected id must be added to the new list .

Comment: @SahilKumar thank's for your answer , i try something like this in Adapter:

public List<Integer> myNumbers() {

        if (items.isChecked()) {

            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

            list.add(Integer.valueOf(items.getIdText2()));
            return  list;
        }
        return null;
    }
Then i call function in activity, and when i debug , on isChecked allways got Items null.

Comment: Initialize the list before condition and return list in both cases whether it is empty or filled with items